# Cannot find VM options file (Pycharm Community 5.03)

Tags: pycharm

Whenever I attempt to start Pycharm i get the message:
Cannot find VM options file.
Pycharm does not work because of this.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you're talking about the first launch after you have downloaded it.
Then it's important that you run `pycharm.sh` from the `bin` folder.
The vm options file is also located there and the path in the script is relative.

Answer (score 2):

the vm options file is missing, you may manually create one:
`pycharm/bin/pycharm.exe.vmoptions` https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Answer (score 0):

run the `pycharm.sh` with super user. for that follow the instruction:
open a terminal and run:

```
sudo su
```

enter your admin password. go to the installation folder and run the:

```
. /pycharm-2021.1.2/bin/pycharm.sh
```

it should work.